# DbContextOptionsBuilder does not Contain a Definition for UseSQLServer after 5.0.11 Upgrade

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Today we updated our Nuget packages for EntityFrameworkCore to version 5.0.11. Unfortunately, that seems to have messed up my VS environment. Whenever I try to compile I get the error message: `Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` match at version 5.0.11 after the upgrade.

I tried downgrading back to 5.0.7 but that did not fix the issue. Restarting the computer did not work. Neither did restarting Visual Studio 2019. I did clean and rebuild the project but that also kept the same error message. The project does reference `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` and it is listed within my .csproj file. Any other advice to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Edit: I should say that this only occurs on my machine so it's more of an issue with the environment. No other changes have been made other than upgrading the nuget package. I did upgrade back to 5.0.11 and it matches what is in the .csproj file. Wondering if this happened to anyone else as well.

Comment: As long as you have a package reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and are importing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace, that's all you need. I'd try the usual of restarting VS, rebooting, checking the .NET  SDK is installed properly etc. Does it work if you do `dotnet build` from the command line?

Comment: try to manually remove all the `Bin` and `Obj` directories in all projects. And the `package` and `.vs` directories, if you have them. Often required for me after a package upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for both of your help! @JHBonarius your suggestion worked as deleting the Bin and Obj folders from all of the projects and rebuilding worked. Mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience I know that just cleaning the build doesn't remove everything. Especially when upgrading dependencies (packages) it's often required to manually delete the `Bin` and `Obj` directories of (all) the projects.

In some cases it's also required to delete the `.vs` and `packages` directories from (all) projects and solution. Don't do this while the solution is open in VS.